# Recortar y ordenar array de objetos JSON por valor numerico

Tags: php, json

Necesito saber como modificar con PHP un array JSON que me devuelve una consulta a una API.
El código que tengo me muestra un gran listado.
Lo que quiero es ordenar y solo mostrar las 3 monedas mas caras del mercado de las muchas que hay.
Estoy probando con la función asort, ksort...pero no lo consigo.
Gracias

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");


$data=[{"symbol":"ETHBTC","price":"0.03572700"},{"symbol":"LTCBTC","price":"0.00374300"},{"symbol":"BNBBTC","price":"0.00624000"},{"symbol":"NEOBTC","price":"0.00100100"},{"symbol":"QTUMETH","price":"0.00556900"},{"symbol":"EOSETH","price":"0.00317900"},{"symbol":"SNTETH","price":"0.00008992"},{"symbol":"BNTETH","price":"0.00365100"},{"symbol":"BCCBTC","price":"0.07908100"},{"symbol":"GASBTC","price":"0.00024330"}]


foreach ($data as $moneda => $info)
{

    echo "<h3> $moneda </h3>";
    echo "<p>";
    echo "<b> Moneda: </b> " . $info["symbol"] . " <br> ";
    echo "<b> Precio: </b> " . $info["price"] . " <br> ";
    echo "</p>";

}
```

No consigo que funcione.

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");


$data=[{"symbol":"ETHBTC","price":"0.03572700"},{"symbol":"LTCBTC","price":"0.00374300"},{"symbol":"BNBBTC","price":"0.00624000"},{"symbol":"NEOBTC","price":"0.00100100"},{"symbol":"QTUMETH","price":"0.00556900"},{"symbol":"EOSETH","price":"0.00317900"},{"symbol":"SNTETH","price":"0.00008992"},{"symbol":"BNTETH","price":"0.00365100"},{"symbol":"BCCBTC","price":"0.07908100"},{"symbol":"GASBTC","price":"0.00024330"}];


function comparar($a, $b)
 {
     if ((int) $a['p'] == (int) $b['p']) {
         return 0;
     }
     return ((int) $a['p'] < (int) $b['p']) ? -1 : 1;
 }
 $array = json_decode($data, true);
 $todosordenados = usort($array, 'comparar');
 $losprimerostres = array_slice($todosordenados,0,3);


foreach ($losprimerostres as $moneda => $info)
{


    echo "<h3> $moneda </h3>";
    echo "<p>";
    echo "<b> Moneda: </b> " . $info["symbol"] . " <br> ";
    echo "<b> Precio: </b> " . $info["price"] . " <br> ";
    echo "</p>";

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Primero pasa el json a array, luego ordenar con el usort de php, y si el atributo "p" siempre es un entero puedes usar la función comparar:

```
function comparar($a, $b)
{
    if ((int) $a['p'] == (int) $b['p']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ((int) $a['p'] < (int) $b['p']) ? -1 : 1;
}
$array = json_decode($data, true);
$todosordenados = array_slice(usort($array, 'comparar'));
```

**Te explico:**
La función `array_slice()` permite extraer una parte de un array. Esta función puede recibir hasta 4 parámetros: el array de entrada, el índice, la longitud y un valor booleano para indicar si se quiere reordenar los índices del array o no.

Éxitos!

Comment: Grandioso! fantastico! un millon de gracias funciona perfecto.

Comment: Como podría hacer para recortar solo la salida a 3 resultados. gracias otra vez

Comment: Si te ha servido la respuesta, márcala como correcta, así si otra persona tiene la misma duda, también la pueda implementar.  @JoseAlvarez

Comment: @JoseAlvarez he modificado el código para mostrar solamente los primeros 3.

Comment: No me funciona, puede ser que este vacia $losprimerostres?

Comment: Prueba ahora! @JoseAlvarez

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, estoy probado de todo pero no llego a más. Gracias otra vez por tu tiempo Amilcar

Comment: @JoseAlvarez cometí un error de escribir como variable la función de usort. Lo he reparado y probado. Funciona correctamente.